# Ajuda com imagens dinâmicas no ReactJS

Tags: react, front-end, jsx

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]> Meu código está retornando o valor em string no console, porem não retorna a imagem mesmo o caminho estando certo no scr. Não sei qual meu erro.Peço ajuda sou novato na linguagem. abaixo está meu código:

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
import Servico from './servico';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import CardDeck from 'react-bootstrap/CardDeck';

function ServicesList() {

  return (
   <div>
           {Servico.Servico.map((servicoDetail,)=>{
               return <div key={servicoDetail.Posicao}>
               <CardDeck>
                 <Card>
                   
                 <Card.Img variant="top" src={servicoDetail.Imagem} alt={servicoDetail.Imagem} />
                 <Card.Body>
                 <Card.Title>{servicoDetail.Titulo}</Card.Title>
                 <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{servicoDetail.Subtitulo}</Card.Subtitle>
                 <Card.Text>
                   This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                   additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                 </Card.Text>
                 </Card.Body>
                  
                </Card>
              </CardDeck>
</div>

           })}
    </div>
      );
}

export default ServicesList;
```

Comment: Como está chegando a URL da imagem?

Comment: tanto como ../imagem.png quanto imagem.png n consigo botar para funcionar.

Comment: Se você colocar o valor da string estaticamente dentro do `src`, ela aparece? Isso me parece um problema de servidor, você tem uma rota estática para acessar as imagens?

Comment: colocando o caminho estático funciona, essas imagens estão no meu computador.

Comment: As imagens estão dentro da src/ do seu projeto ou em outro diretório do seu computador? Pergunto isso porque elas devem estar sendo servidas por um servidor web para funcionar corretamente

Comment: Pessoal de uma empresa me passou um json local.